# Can't Reset a Simple Radio Button - React JS

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I am writing a trivia app. When I select an answer, I check if it is the right one and get a new question right after. The problem is that I can't get the React to render the selected radio button when it is the wrong answer.

[Screenshot of what it looks like](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11292468/arpitha-chandrashekara)

I am generating the Trivia questions from a JSON file. I have to make a input and a label tag dynamically. This is what I have so far:

I can get my next question when the selected one is right, but it doesn't show any radio selected. My `isRadioChecked` starts with `false`. I also tried `checked={this.state.isRadioChecked == object}`.

Below, I check if the clicked radio was the right answer and my ***render*** method

```
 checkResult = event => {
    this.setState(
      {
        selectedAnswer: event.target.value
      },
      () => {
        if (this.state.selectedAnswer === this.state.correctAnswer) {
          this.setState(
            {
              isRadioChecked: false,
              currentQuestionNumber: this.state.currentQuestionNumber + 1
            },
            () => {
              this.getNewQuestion();
            }
          );

render() {
    return (
      <div onChange={this.checkResult}>
        <h2>Question Component</h2>
        <h3>{this.displayQuestion()}</h3>
        <div>{this.displayAlternatives()}</div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

I really appreciate your help. Thank You!!

[EDIT]

Thank You, [Arpitha](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11292468/arpitha-chandrashekara) that was the first thing I tried and actually my last attempts came straight from http://react.tips/radio-buttons-in-reactjs/ . I think the issue is that I am creating the radios using dynamic data.

Anyways, I did change it to like it was before and still, I get no visible selected radio, even though the log shows the selected answer.

```
 setUpAnswers() {
    let tempAnswerArray = this.mergeAnswers(this.state.currentQuestionNumber);
    tempAnswerArray = tempAnswerArray.map((object, i) => renderHTML(object));
    console.log(tempAnswerArray[0]);

    tempAnswerArray = tempAnswerArray.map((object, i) => (
      <div key={i}>
        <input
          type="radio"
          name="answers"
          checked={this.state.selectedAnswer === object}
          onChange={this.handleOptionChange}
          id={object}
          value={object}
        />
        <label htmlFor={object}>{object}</label>
      </div>
    ));

    this.setState({
      answerArray: tempAnswerArray
    });
  }
  //*************************************************** */
  handleOptionChange = changeEvent => {
    this.setState(
      {
        selectedAnswer: changeEvent.target.value
      },
      () => {
        console.log(this.state.selectedAnswer);
      }
    );
  };
```

Answer (score 0):

You are assigning `this.state.isRadioChecked` status to all the radio buttons like this `checked={this.state.isRadioChecked}` . So all the radio buttons will be checked or unchecked at the same time.

Instead you can use `state.selectedAnswer` to update checked attribute of radio button. Something like this -

```
checked={this.state.selectedAnswer === object}
```

A nice article on how to create radio groups is explained here - http://react.tips/radio-buttons-in-reactjs/